# $\sigma$-algebra generated by functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, functions

I'm working on an exercise that asks you to find $\sigma(u)$, where $u$ is defined as

- $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, u(x) = x$
- $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, u(x) = |x|$
- $u:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, u(x,y) = x^2+y^2$

I know that

$$\sigma(u) = u^{-1}(\mathcal{B}) = \{u^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal{B}\}$$

with $\mathcal{B}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

And that for $B\in\mathcal{B}$
$$u^{-1}(B) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}:u(x)\in B\}$$

For $u(x)=x$ it's clear to me that $\sigma(u)=\mathcal{B}$

For $u(x)=|x|$ what I did was the following,
$$|x|\in (a,b) \implies (x < -a \lor  x > a) \land (-b < x < b)$$

So I think that
$$\sigma(u) = \sigma\{((-\infty,-a)\cup(a,\infty))\cap(-b,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
I'm not quite sure about this last part, and even if I'm right I don't know if there is a better way to define the set.

Finally, for $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ I'm a little bit lost. I know that $a<x^2+y^2<b$ creates 'discs' on the plane but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not give a complete description in the case $u(x)=|x|$. You can describe $\sigma  (u)$ as the collection of all symmetric Borel sets: those Borel sets $B$ for which $x \in B$ if and only if $-x \in B$.

For $u(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}$, denote by $S$ the unit circle in $\mathbb R^{2}$. You can write $\sigma  (u)$ as the collection of all sets of the form $(B_1 \times A_1) \cup (B_2 \times A_2)$ where $A_1,A_2 \in\{\emptyset, \mathbb R^{2}, S, \mathbb R^{2}\setminus S\}$ and $B_1,B_2$ are Borel sets in $[0,\infty)$. You can also describe this as the collection of al Borel sets $E$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$ such that $(x,y) \in E$ implies that the entire circle with center at the origin and radius $r=\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ is contained in $E$.